# sql join four tables and calculate average

Tags: sql, join, average, calculated-columns

How would I get a query that joins these four tables, and also gives me the average?

```
Table1:
TeamId |   TeamName
  1    |      TA
  2    |      TB
  3    |      TC

Table2:
YearsId  | Years
    1    | 2009-2010
    2    | 2010-2011
    3    | 2011-2012

Table3:
MonthsId | Month
    1    |  July
    2    |  Aug
    3    |  Sept

Table4:
TeamId  | MonthsId  | YearsId  | TeamWinCount
    1   |     1     |    2     |        44
    1   |     1     |    3     |        11
    1   |     2     |    2     |        0
    1   |     12    |    3     |        13
    2   |     1     |    2     |        33
```

I would like to get results that look like this:

```
   Year    |  Team   | Avg (avg win count jun+aug+sept+.../12)
 2009-2010 |   TA    |   23.3
 2009-2010 |   TB    |   18.23    
 2009-2010 |   TC    |   35.23    
 2010-2011 |   TA    |   18.23    
 2010-2011 |   TB    |   18.23    
 2010-2011 |   TC    |   18.23
```

If there is no entry for a month, it should be counted as 0

There must be some genius out there's that's done this before.  I've played around with joining the tables, but can't seem to get a column that is the average.  Any help or direction is much appreciated!

Comment: You should post what you have so far.  Its easier to just add the AVG column to an existing query than writting the whole thing

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps this will do as a starting point?  select year,team,average(teamwincount) from table4 natural join table 2 natural join table 1 group by team,year

Comment: The existing queries i had didn't really get me much, just joining all tables, but this gives me many more rows than i want:

select 
 *
FROM table1 T1
cross join Years
cross join Months
inner join table4 t4 ON t1.YearsId = Years.YearsId AND t4.MonthsId = Months.MonthsId

Comment: @Akash: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with the keyword "Natural", i'm using MSFT SQL Server, and it's not coming up as a usable word.  Also, don't I need table3 in there somewhere to calculate counts for each month to get the average?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join  I'm not sure what the equivalent would be for you, but just equating the correct columns in a where clause should do.  Didnt notice earlier that you wanted a 0 if the month didnt exist.  My idea will fail in that case.(That is one of the reasons I didnt need table3)

Comment: HLGEM's solution seems like a good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table3` is not needed here

```
SELECT Table2.Years,Table1.TeamName,IFNULL(AVG(TeamWinCount), 0) AS TeamWinCount
FROM Table2
CROSS JOIN Table1
LEFT JOIN Table4 ON Table1.TeamId=Table4.TeamId AND Table2.YearsId=Table4.YearsId
GROUP BY Table2.Years,Table1.TeamName
```

Comment: but it is if you want a 0 included in the average when there are no wins that month.

Comment: thanks, edited (and added `IFNULL`). because there is no need to output a month, it doesn't matter if there is no data for some month. `AVG` calculated the average for available data based on `Table4`

Comment: Awesome! elegant, simple, and works like a charm.  Thanks!  PS. didn't know the AVG function was so smart, that's very good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK as I see it your problem is first you need a list of all possible year/month/ team combinations, then once you have that you want to convert any null values for wincount to 0, then you want to do the average.

I'd try some variation on this:

```
select Years, TeamName, avg(wincount)
from 
(Select  Years, Month, TeamName, case when Wincount is null then 0  else  Wincount
from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
cross join tabl3 t3
left join table4 t4 
on t1.teamid = t4.teamid and t2.yearsId = t4.yearsId
    and t3.MonthsId = t4.monthsId) a
group by Years, TeamName
```